# Generalisation error bound proof for the Adaboost algorithm, corollary 4.4 in Freund and Schapire (2014)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, boosting, adaboost

I am having difficulty with a detail in the proof of generalisation error bounds for the AdaBoost algorithm, and would appreciate some assistance. This is the proof of corollary 4.4 on page 54 of  [*Boosting: Foundations and Algorithms*](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/Boosting_%20Foundations%20and%20Algorithms%20%5BSchapire%20%26%20Freund%202012-05-18%5D.pdf) by Freund and Schapire (2014).

I have rendered the part where I am experiencing 'compilation' errors in bold:

> **Corollary 4.4** Assume, in addition to the assumptions of theorem 4.3, that each base classifier has weighted error $\epsilon_t \leq \frac{1}{2} - \gamma$ for some $\gamma > 0$. Let the number of rounds $T$ be equal to the smallest integer exceeding $(\ln m)/(2 \gamma^2)$. Then with probability at least $1 - \delta$, the generalization error of the combined classifier $H$ will be at most
>
> $$O \left(\frac{1}{m} \left[\frac{(\ln m)(\ln m + \ln \vert \mathcal{H} \vert)}{\gamma^2} + \ln \left( \frac{1}{\delta} \right)\right] \right).$$
>
> **Proof.** By theorem 3.1, the training error of the combined classifier is at most $\exp({-2 \gamma^2T}) < 1 /m$. **Since there are $m$ examples, this means that the training error must actually be zero.** Applying the second part of theorem 4.3 gives the result.

*I am unable to understand the reasoning in bold, and have a feeling that there is something obvious I am missing. Can someone elaborate? I have supplied further context and my attempt at parsing this below.*

**Additional context.**

The above extract refers to additional context, in particular, theorem 3.1 of the same book. This is the standard result from [Freund and Schapire (1997)](https://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/Boosting-Ensemble/decision-theoretic_generalization.pdf) concerning exponential bounds on AdaBoost training error:

> **Theorem 3.1.** Given the notation of algorithm 1.1, let $\gamma_t := \frac{1}{2} - \epsilon_t$ and let $D_1$ be an arbitrary initial distribution over the training set. Then the weighted training error of the combined classifier $H$ with respect to $D_1$ is bounded as
>
> $$\mathbb{P}_{i \sim D_1} \left(H(x_i) \neq y_i \right) \leq \prod^T_{t=1} \sqrt{1 - 4 \gamma_t^2} \leq \exp \left(-2 \sum^T_{t=1} \gamma_t^2 \right).$$

For completeness, the assumptions from theorem 4.3 which are referred to in corollary 4.4 are that *"AdaBoost is run for $T$ rounds on $m \geq T$ random examples, using base classifiers from a finite space $\mathcal{H}$."*

Parsing the first line of corollary 4.4, set $\gamma_t = \gamma$ for all $t = 1, \dots T$. Then with $T = \lceil (\ln m) / 2 \gamma^2 \rceil > (\ln m) / 2 \gamma^2$, where $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ is a *strict* ceiling function, I got

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}_{i \sim D_1} \left(H(x_i) \neq y_i \right) &\leq \exp \left(-2 \sum^T_{t=1} \gamma_t^2 \right) \\
&= \exp(-2 \gamma^2T) \\
&< \exp \left(-2 \gamma^2 \frac{\ln m}{2 \gamma^2} \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{m}.
\end{align}$$

At this stage, it is no longer clear to me what argument would be obvious or natural to propose in order show that $\mathbb{P}_{i \sim D_1} \left(H(x_i) \neq y_i \right) = 0$.